# Unable to install mysqli extension, Using php 7.2

Tags: php, mysqli

I am using linux mint, apache2, mySQL 5.7, php 7.2 now.

I was trying to execute basic php login web page on my local server which is http://192.168.xxx.xxx/ but when I login my page, the white page is always appears.

I tried to install php mysqli extension, so I wrote commands on terminal as below :

```
taylor@C10ud-9 ~ $ sudo apt-get install php-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php-mysql is already the newest version (1:7.0+35ubuntu6.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
taylor@C10ud-9 ~ $ sudo apt-get install php-mysqlnd
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Note, selecting 'php7.0-mysql' instead of 'php-mysqlnd'
php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
taylor@C10ud-9 ~ $ sudo apt-get install php7.0-mysql
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
php7.0-mysql is already the newest version (7.0.25-0ubuntu0.16.04.1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 2 not upgraded.
taylor@C10ud-9 ~ $ phpenmod mysqli
WARNING: Module mysqli ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
WARNING: Module mysqli ini file doesn't exist under /etc/php/7.2/mods-available
```

but mysqli can't be found.

Comment: Try installing `php7.2-mysql`

Comment: I had 3 error messages that E: Unable to locate package php7.2-mysql
E: Couldn't find any package by glob 'php7.2-mysql'
E: Couldn't find any package by regex 'php7.2-mysql'

Comment: how did you install PHP 7.2 initially?

Comment: As I remember I did just installed apache2 and mysql ! How could php be started?